# Using LINQ First() method shows "Possible multiple iteration of IEnumerable" warning by Resharper

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

I have code like this:

> Person firstPerson = personsEnumerable.First();

, where `personsEnumerable` is `IEnumerable<Person>`

Now, Resharper underlines the personsEnumerable variable and says "Possible iteration of IEnumerable". I understand what this warning means from other questions here on SO, but I'm wondering why it's showing it in my example? I think First() returns the first element and there's no need to iterate the collection at all ?

Is this a 'general' warning message which is not applicable in my case (and I can ignore it) or I don't understand how First() actually works ?

Comment: _"I think First() returns the first element and there's no need to iterate the collection at all"_ Even if you only want the first, the query must be executed. However, i assume that you access `personsEnumerable` multiple times.

Comment: Show us rest of the code. You are iterating the sequence twice, that could mean redundant data retrieval.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it returns the first element but it still creates an enumerator to get that first element.You could add `ToArray` or `ToList` after `Where` to prevent this. However if you want to just get the first element, you could use the [overloaded version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of `First` which takes a `Func` delegate and you can remove the `Where`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this code:

```
var personsEnumerable = peopleList.OrderBy(p => p.Age);
var firstPerson = personsEnumerable.First();
foreach (var p in personsEnumerable)
{
    // whatever
}
```

The first line of code sets things up to sort the list and create the results, but it doesn't actually *do* anything until you try to enumerate it. The second line of code, then would end up doing the sort. So although you're not enumerating the entire result, you're executing code to produce the result. And for a sort, that would entail doing all the heavy lifting.

The `foreach` loop would *do the sort again* before actually enumerating the results.

Comment: wondering if a personsEnumerable.Any() will also do the sorting stuff?

Comment: @GregorValentin: Yes.

Comment: thank you, good to know! from msdn: "The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined." So ImO you can ignore the Warning  in this case.

Comment: @GregorValentin: You probably don't want to ignore that warning. In the above case, if you replaced `First()` with `Any()`, the call to `Any()` would incur the cost of the sort. And so would the `foreach`. Not a problem if there's just a handful of items, but if your `peopleList` had a million items in it, you'd definitely notice the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. Very Helpful!